# Sockets Linux - Dúvida

Tags: c

Porque usar essas funções com implementações de sockets e para que elas servem?

```
select()
FD_SET()
FD_CLR()
FD_ZERO()
```

Comment: Sua pergunta foi para na fila de análise de "posts de baixa qualidade" e sinalizada para fechamento... Pode dar um pouquinho mais de contexto?

Comment: Olá, siga a dica do brasofilo e nos diga de onde são essas funções. Aparentemente elas não são de uma biblioteca padrão, ou pelo menos não muito conhecidas. Aproveite e faça um [tour] e confira o guia [ask] para tirar o máximo de proveito da comunidade.

Comment: No site: [Handle multiple socket connections with fd_set and select on Linux](http://www.binarytides.com/multiple-socket-connections-fdset-select-linux/), tem um exemplo utilizando select para tratar múltiplas conexões no Linux. E neste link [A scalable client/server using select() socket function](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20066/A-scalable-client-server-using-select-socket-funct) tem um exemplo de utilização com Windows.  Para Windows, a documentação da [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141(v=vs.85).aspx) também vale a pena. (links em inglês).